# Segue To Navigation Controller in Tab Bar Controller

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

In my application, I have a default tab selected for my Tab Bar Controller. On the viewDidLoad() of the default tab, I have this:

```
if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("defaultCode") == nil) {
    //let navController:UINavigationController = UINavigationController()
    //self.presentViewController(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.tabBarController!.selectedIndex = 1
```

I thought calling selectedIndex would do what I was looking forever; however, it only changes the selected tab in the TabBar, but my view does not change. The area I commented out quickly shows the proper view, then goes to a black screen. The view I am trying to switch to is a Navigation Controller

Answer (score 0):

selectedIndex always be the first and pop/push after selected

Comment: This post isn't an actual attempt at answering the question. Please note [StackOverflow doesn't work like a discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), it is a Q&A site where every post is either a question or an answer to a question. Posts can also have [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - small sentences like this one - that can be used to critique or request clarification from an author. This should be either a comment or a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)